# make array of objects follow path via curves modifier

Tags: bezier-curves

Im trying to follow the blender guru tunnel tutorial.

I have have a tunnel using 4 objects and added array modifiter to then to make the tunnel effect.

[image]
I add a path object and add the curve modidifer to the "arch" object, but as soon as i do that the arch object gets rotated.. i have tried all 6 angles and none of them gives the result i want as in the tutorial.

Here is the result after adding the curves modifier

[image]

Comment: Try Ctrl + A > Rotation.

Comment: See if answers here help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/why-does-adding-a-curve-modifier-move-my-object-to-the-center-of-the-curve/64581#64581

Comment: you where right, i had not appliced my scaling and rotation of the objects... still learning.. thx alot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to apply my scaling and rotation of my objects.. still learning.. thx alot for helping out