# Applying a curve modifier to an extruded plane causes plane to become a line

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Surely this is some setting that is wrong, but what?? I trying to bend an extruded plane using the curve modifier, but as soon as I select the bezier curve in the modifier, I lose all dimensions of the plane!  [Top down ortho of plane & bezier curve before modifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfdpl.png)

[image: Select the modifier curve & poof!]

Comment: Probably something with the curve, e.g. its Radius parameter (see in Edit mode on the Properties shelf > top rollout, it should be set to 1 to get expected behaviour), but not necessarily. If you can [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the  blend and include link here

Comment: Is there any scale or rotation involved?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/why-does-adding-a-curve-modifier-move-my-object-to-the-center-of-the-curve and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier . This has been asked countless times, I'm sure following the steps on those questions will yield good results.

Answer (score 1):

There was a scaling problem (even though I applied scaling & rotation) but I couldn't find the Transform > Radius that Ramos described. I found that if I zoomed in far enough, what I thought was a line was the horribly deformed extruded plane. I tried numerous re-scaling of both the plane & the curve, and with the hint that Mr Zak supplied, went to the Bezier curve's shape properties, and unchecked 'radius' (path/curve deform) and set Minimum's Smooth (Twisting) value from 0 to 6.00. Mostly by luck(?) I got the desired results. Mission accomplished! Thanks all. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a flat path using only a curve object, by setting the extrude property. You can also add a solidify modifier to give it some thickness.

[image: extruded path]

The extrusion may not align the way you want at first, adjust the tilt to get it right, which can be found in the properties region <kbd>N</kbd>. You can use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to adjust the tilt interactively.

[image: curves tilt property]

If you want a mesh object after you have created your path, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*->Mesh From Curve* will turn it into a mesh.