# Curve modifier not working

Tags: modifiers

I'm currently making a race track in blender and i'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDLLbKvEeBY. At 7:04 in the video he adds the curve modifier and sets it to the bezier. Whenever I add the curve modifier and set it to the bezier,the "cube" just disappears.

Edit: I changed the axis in the curve modifier and now it looks like this.
[image]

File here: [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with Curve Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use search before asking see, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/why-does-adding-a-curve-modifier-move-my-object-to-the-center-of-the-curve and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier

Comment: Try Just Changing Axis in the curve modifier. (Try to check all the axis it must work with any of the axis)