# Getting the curve modifier to work

Tags: bezier-curves

I have been using Blender for about a year and I sill don't know much. I was recently messing with the curves and watching tutorials when I stumbled into something weird. When I added the curve modifier to my shark and binded it to the curve the shark turned into a whole new shape, and when I tried shrinking it, but then my shark was 2d. If anyone knows anything please help me.[image]
[image]

Actually I got it to work by redoing the curve, but I ran into a different problem.

Comment: The secret to following curves is to ensure both the shark and curve share the same origin point.  Also using CTL-A on a rescaled object can cause distortion problems.  Best to try it without this first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with Curve Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/why-does-adding-a-curve-modifier-move-my-object-to-the-center-of-the-curve also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ when an object has a Curve modifier it's deformed. Also, perhaps your curve vertices have been twisted or scaled, in that case select them all and alt T, and W > Set Curve Radius

Comment: Thank you I figured it out, i just deleted and re-did the curve